# optimizing a website mockup for portfolio

Tags: adobe-fireworks, mockup

I saved my website mockup as a jpeg and the highest quality but when i upload it to my portfolio and see how it looks i notice the quality is worse still. The proper size is not showing as well. Anyone know why?

Comment: Have you tried using a different format?

Comment: What image size are you uploading, resolution and file size

Answer (score -1):

What medium are you uploading it to? A .jpeg on a website? If your portfolio is online, it may be CSS or HTML that is formatting the picture a specific size which may be causing it to be distorted.

Comment: I am using a portfolio template. [ carbon made ] so i have no control over the html or css. Maybe they have it limited to a certain size? I also tried png 24 with the same results.

Comment: What platform is it on? Wordpress? Cargo collective?

Comment: The platform is called carbon made.

Comment: I am not familiar with carbon made. Make sure its at the correct with and height suggestions. Alternatives are to display it as a live website, or look into another way to display your portfolio.